# Classify many documents with many different unordered items

Tags: classification, text-mining

I've the following documents with different unordered items, e.g.,

1. doc_1:

   - item 1,
   - item 2,
     ...
   - item n
2. doc_2:

   - item 7,
   - item 3,
     ...
   - item n
     .
     .
     .
3. doc_n:

   - item 20,
   - item 17,
     ...
   - item n

how To classify into similar groups, e.g.,

1- doc_1:
     all  item 1

2- doc_2:
     all  item 2

...etc.

Comment: What do you mean by itesm? Are they lines in your docs? You can iterate all docs to collect the items

Comment: Yes lines in a document., how to collect similar items in different documents?

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, `How to collect similar items in different documents?`, I am assuming you want to compute similarity score between lines in a document to the lines in another document.

One simple approach is to represent one line/sentence of a document through [bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) model. Then you can compute cosine similarity of two sentence/line representations.

Given two lines of two different documents are textually very close, you should observe higher cosine similarity between their sentence representation.

Please note, a useful representation and similarity computation depends on the problem that you are trying to solve. Say for example, if different documents contain product reviews (one or more lines) associated with different products (cell phones, laptops) and you want to collect the lines associated with a single product, you can simply follow the approach mentioned above.

Also note, the solution I have suggested, its pretty naive. To achieve higher accuracy in your desired task, you may need to design more focused which will be effective for the target task.

Comment: Thanks Dr. W. Ahmad, I'll try your idea.